# ros control assertion failed

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, ros-control, hardware-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wrote a custom controller for my robot. I used ros control boilerplate (by dave coleman) for hardware interface. The code compiles but I get the following error.

```
myrobot_hw_main: /opt/ros/lunar/include/hardware_interface/posvel_command_interface.h:72: void hardware_interface::PosVelJointHandle::setCommandVelocity(double): Assertion `cmd_vel_' failed.
[myrobot/myrobot_hardware_interface-1] process has died [pid 96416, exit code -6, cmd /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/control_pkg/myrobot_hw_main __name:=myrobot_hardware_interface __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/aee6bd46-702a-11e8-82d2-000c29ad2621/myrobot-myrobot_hardware_interface-1.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/aee6bd46-702a-11e8-82d2-000c29ad2621/myrobot-myrobot_hardware_interface-1*.log
```

I wrote a controller for omni drive and if I understand it properly, this is where the problem is. I used this interface called PosVelJointInterface from posvel_command_interface.h. The problem occurs when I executed the following lines. Basically in my controller, I take in the twist command, do some math and generate four velocities which I'm trying to populate using the setCommandVelocity method.

```
hardware_interface::PosVelJointHandle wheel_1;    
wheel_1.setCommandVelocity(wheelVelocities.velocity[0]);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294212/ros-control-assertion-failed/) by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2018-06-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the sources ([here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/f38bf6d7c21e744e37b254d86f1ab7796ea803f7/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/posvel_command_interface.h#L79)), `cmd_vel_` is a pointer to a double that gets initialised in the ctor ([here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/f38bf6d7c21e744e37b254d86f1ab7796ea803f7/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/posvel_command_interface.h#L53)).

The code you show ("The problem occurs when I executed the following lines") doesn't initialise the `PosVelJointHandle` properly (or at least: it doesn't provide any values for the arguments), it's using [this ctor](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/f38bf6d7c21e744e37b254d86f1ab7796ea803f7/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/posvel_command_interface.h#L45), which sets all pointers to `0`. If you then try to use `setCommandVelocity(..)`, the assert is triggered.

Two comments:

1. if you're writing a controller, why are you intantiating `hardware_interface` classes directly? Shouldn't that be the responsibility of your / a `hardware_interface` implementation for your robot?
2. read up / find examples of how to initialise a `PosVelJointHandle` correctly and update your code (if you have determined you really should be intantiating those classes yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-06-18**:
I realised the mistake and solved the problem. Forgot to close the issue. My apologies. Thank you for taking your time in helping me out here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-18**:
Could you help future readers by describing how you eventually solved your problem?

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-06-18**:
I found a way [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/melodic-devel/diff_drive_controller/include/diff_drive_controller/diff_drive_controller.h). This is available in ROS controllers git repo. Instead of using a PosVelJointHandle, I used the JointHandle and JointStateInterface ..

**Comment by [venkisagunner](https://answers.ros.org/users/29258/venkisagunner/) on 2018-06-18**:
And integrating that with the boilerplate was trivial. In my previous approach, I declared the joint handles but didnt call the getHandle (line 319) method which resulted in no resource allocation. When I ran rosrun controller_manager controller_manager myrobot/list_controllers, I found no resources